# Syntax error raw sql on rails when query inner results

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

how do you query raw SQL on rails?

So I have this raw sql that I need to run on rails but giving me a syntax error. I also escape the extra parenthesis but still got a syntax error near the first inner join.

here's my code:

```
Spree::CorporateAccount.joins(" (((((
                ( inner join spree_memberships on spree_corporate_accounts.id = spree_memberships.corporate_account_id)
                inner join spree_users on spree_memberships.user_id = spree_users.id) 
                left join  spree_variant_price_sets on spree_corporate_accounts.variant_price_set_id = spree_variant_price_sets.id)
                left join  spree_addresses on spree_corporate_accounts.bill_address_id = spree_addresses.id)
                left join  spree_states on spree_addresses.state_id = spree_states.id)
                left join  spree_countries on spree_addresses.country_id = spree_countries.id)
                left join  spree_partner_accounts on spree_corporate_accounts.id = spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_id 
                ").where(" spree_memberships.deleted_at IS null 
                  AND (spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' OR spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_type IS NULL)
                  AND admin = true 
                  ")
```

but on sql this is perfectly fine.

```
SELECT 
spree_corporate_accounts.id,
spree_corporate_accounts.company_name,
spree_memberships.ADMIN,
spree_users.email,
spree_users.doctor AS name,
spree_partner_accounts.account_key,
CASE spree_corporate_accounts.billing_type when 1 THEN 'Postbill' WHEN 2 THEN 'Creditcard' ELSE 'Individual'END,
spree_variant_price_sets.name AS priceset,
spree_addresses.address1,
spree_addresses.address2,
spree_addresses.city,
spree_addresses.zipcode,
spree_states.name AS state,
spree_countries.name AS country,
spree_addresses.phone,
spree_users.created_at 
from (((((( spree_corporate_accounts inner join spree_memberships on spree_corporate_accounts.id = spree_memberships.corporate_account_id)
inner join spree_users on spree_memberships.user_id = spree_users.id) 
left join  spree_variant_price_sets on spree_corporate_accounts.variant_price_set_id = spree_variant_price_sets.id)
left join  spree_addresses on spree_corporate_accounts.bill_address_id = spree_addresses.id)
left join  spree_states on spree_addresses.state_id = spree_states.id)
left join  spree_countries on spree_addresses.country_id = spree_countries.id)
left join  spree_partner_accounts on spree_corporate_accounts.id = spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_id 
where spree_memberships.deleted_at IS null 
and  (spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' OR spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_type IS NULL )
AND admin = true
```

if I do this. It will yield a different result. so what im thinking is the parenthesis evaluate the result first and then go to the next.

```
Spree::CorporateAccount.joins("inner join spree_memberships on spree_corporate_accounts.id = spree_memberships.corporate_account_id")
                                       .joins("inner join spree_users on spree_memberships.user_id = spree_users.id")
                                       .joins("left join  spree_variant_price_sets on spree_corporate_accounts.variant_price_set_id = spree_variant_price_sets.id")
                                       .joins("left join  spree_addresses on spree_corporate_accounts.bill_address_id = spree_addresses.id")
                                       .joins("left join  spree_states on spree_addresses.state_id = spree_states.id")
                                       .joins("left join  spree_countries on spree_addresses.country_id = spree_countries.id")
                                       .joins("left join  spree_partner_accounts on spree_corporate_accounts.id = spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_id ")
                                       .where("spree_memberships.deleted_at IS null
                                        AND spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' OR spree_partner_accounts.partnerable_type IS NULL
                                        AND admin = true
                                        ")
```

Comment: Could use a heredoc with the sql then. `sql = <<-SQL [your query] <<-SQL` and then use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` to call it

Comment: @MikeHeft Thank you for the reply sir. I have that idea before but when I tested it doesn't return the model. I need to use the hook from `Spree::CorporateAccount`

Comment: There's `find_by_sql` that might work? ` Spree::CorporateAccount.find_by_sql(sql)`?

Comment: @MikeHeft yea I was thinking of using that too. but I just changed my query structure. I was really off with the parenthesis. thank you sir.

Comment: That was my next suggestion. lol. I've definitely gotten lost in the parenthesis too :P

Comment: @MikeHeft question though is there a difference to remove the parenthesis? tried removing it and there was no difference but on rails there is.

Comment: To my knowledge, there shouldn't be. I think the parenthesis in sql queries are there to assist in grouping things together, unless it's a subquery; in which case they're needed.

Comment: @MikeHeft When I was testing it, It has a different value. I also noticed that by joining model they will do a inner join even though you explicitly say `LEFT JOIN`

so like `Model1.join( LEFT JOIN Model2 on Model2.id = Model1.id)` it will still do a inner join.

Comment: I never said left join. I had just originally made my first suggestion because you said the raw sql works fine :D I'm at a loss :( That's along join. I still get a little turned around when they get that long :( Sorry I couldn't have been of more help :(

Comment: @MikeHeft no sir you already helped me. thank you for doing a good deed sir. appreciate it.